# Why exceptions are thrown in windows-1251?

Tags: php, utf-8

I have my local MySQL server disabled and see appropriate PDO Exception. The problem is that all cyrillic symbols in the message are broken (message text and cyryllic symbols in path):

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] ����������� �� �����������, �.�. �������� ��������� ������ ������ �� �����������. in D:\��� �������\domains\time.local\vendor\time\DB.php:25 Stack trace: #0
>   ...

I've found out that this text is actually in windows-1251 format (shows normal text when I switch to it manually in browser). But I have utf-8 set everywhere: in Apache I have:

> AddDefaultCharset utf-8

(Apache sends proper charset header)

All php files are in UTF-8 without BOM. In php.ini I have:

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"

internal_encoding = "UTF-8"

input_encoding = "UTF-8"

output_encoding = "UTF-8"
```

So why it still uses windows-1251? And how to switch such messages to utf-8?

I also see that fatal error and other also uses windows-1251. Why?

Apache 2.4/PHP 7.0.3/Windows 10

P. S. My exception handler is quite simple:

```
set_exception_handler(function (\Throwable $th) {
    echo $th;
});
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 1):

Try execute query "SET NAMES utf8" after connection to database, maybe it helps.